# Slide panel in from right

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, slide

I'm trying to replicate the effect on this website in the portfolio section where it slides a panel in the full size of the viewport and then slides it out when you click close.

Example here: http://alwayscreative.net/#portfolio

Here's my current markup:

```
<section class="panel" id="portfolio">
    <section class="content">
        <h1>What are you <strong>interested</strong> in?</h1>
        <a class="btn-portfolio" id="btn-commercial" href="#">Commercial</a>
        <a class="btn-portfolio" id="btn-residential" href="#">Residential</a>
    </section>
</section>
```

The .panel section is 100% height and width of the viewport and I'd like 2 different panels to be able to slide in — one for #btn-commercial and one for #btn-residential.

Any ideas how to make this happen?

If it helps any, here's my site so far: http://www.freshbrand.ca/testlink/top40/#portfolio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you would do it with JQuery but clearly you can do it in normal javascript if you prefer. Set up the panels with position absolute in your css:

```
.panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border-width: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.panel inactive{
  display: none;
}
.panel active {
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

in your javascript (after the dom has loaded) get the screen dimensions and set the positions of the inactive elements to just off the right hand edge of the screen:

```
$('.panel').css('width', screen.innerWidth);

var setup = function() {
  $('.portfolio-panel.inactive').css('left', window.innerWidth);
  $('.portfolio-panel.active').css('left', 0);
}
setup();
```

When you wish to slide a panel in from the right, pass its id to the following function:

```
var slideIn = function(panelId) {
  $('#' + panelId).animate({
    left: 0
  }, 400, function () { // animates the #left property from the screen width down to zero (i.e. slide it in from the right hand edge of the screen)
    // tidy up
    $('.portfolio-panel.active').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
    $('#'+panelId).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
    setup();
  });
};
```

**EDIT:** The event handler would look something like this:

```
$('.btn-portfolio').click(function() {
  slideIn($(this).attr('id').substr(4)); // extract the panel name from the id and pass it into slideIn
});
```

The only remaining issue is to eliminate the horizontal scroll bar you will probably see during the animation. Just add `overflow-x: hidden;` to the element to which the scroll bar belongs (probably body, but it depends on how you've structured and styled the rest of your site)

Comment: That's awesome Rob! But how do I make the last function run when I click on an element?

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work in a JSFiddle, but I'm not having ANY luck... Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xD6gh/

Comment: Sorry Kevin - I'd written the code without trying it out in a browser (always a mistake!). There were a few typos. It's now fixed and a working jsFiddle is here:  http://jsfiddle.net/xD6gh/1/

Comment: There is actually a remaining bug in the code. If the browser is resized by the user, weird things will happen (divs will be the wrong size and the inactive ones will be in the wrong place). However, I'll leave the code for that to you (hint: http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Answer (score -1):

This is basically a single page website, a lot of jQuery plugins are available for the same.
I personally prefer

http://joelb.me/scrollpath/

Check out it's demo and download the code from github's link

https://github.com/JoelBesada/scrollpath

Hope this helps

Comment: That's not really what I'm after — I need a panel to slide in from the right side of the viewport that is 100% width and then close again when you click a button